# Ruby on Rails error: "Undefined method `call' for "result == false":String" error in create method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, imagemagick, paperclip

When I try to create a listing in my app with an image this error is thrown:

```
undefined method `call' for "result == false":String.
```

The error occurred after I installed devise gem. But devise shouldn't have anything to do with creating a new listing?

The other parts of the app works fine, and I can create new listings without images.

**Error message**

```
NoMethodError in ArtistsController#create

undefined method `call' for "result == false":String
```

**The method it points to is a callback method in ActiveSupport found here on row 164**

https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/rails/rails@master/.rubygem/activesupport/.def/ActiveSupport/Callbacks/$methods/halted_callback_hook

Anyone got any ideas what the issue could be? I'm very new to this, so if you need more information from me or if I need to rephrase my question, just let me know.

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby "2.0.0"

gem 'rails', '4.2.0.beta2'

gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0.0.beta1'
gem "paperclip", "~> 3.0"
gem "paperclip-dropbox", ">= 1.1.7"
gem "figaro"
gem 'devise'

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
```

**Artists_controller, the exception seem to be thrown for the create method in the controller**

```
class ArtistsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_artist, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /artists
  # GET /artists.json
  def index
    @artists = Artist.all
  end

  # GET /artists/1
  # GET /artists/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /artists/new
  def new
    @artist = Artist.new
  end

  # GET /artists/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /artists
  # POST /artists.json
  def create
    @artist = Artist.new(artist_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @artist.save
        format.html { redirect_to @artist, notice: 'Artist was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @artist }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @artist.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /artists/1
  # PATCH/PUT /artists/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @artist.update(artist_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @artist, notice: 'Artist was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @artist.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /artists/1
  # DELETE /artists/1.json
  def destroy
    @artist.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to artists_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_artist
      @artist = Artist.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def artist_params
      params.require(:artist).permit(:name, :description, :price, :image)
    end
end
```

**User class**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

**Artist class (listing model)**

```
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "200x", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url 
    => "/images/:style/missing.png"
    validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

**The form helper**

```
<%= form_for(@artist, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
  <% if @artist.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@artist.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this artist from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @artist.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :description, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :price %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :price, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :image %><br>
    <%= f.file_field :image, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>


<% end %>
```

**Full trace**

```
app/controllers/artists_controller.rb:27:in `create'
activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:161:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:87:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:87:in `run_callbacks'
paperclip (3.5.4) lib/paperclip/callbacks.rb:26:in `run_paperclip_callbacks'
paperclip (3.5.4) lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:419:in `block in post_process'
activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:83:in `run_callbacks'
paperclip (3.5.4) lib/paperclip/callbacks.rb:26:in `run_paperclip_callbacks'
paperclip (3.5.4) lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:418:in `post_process'
paperclip (3.5.4) lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:112:in `assign'
paperclip (3.5.4) lib/paperclip/has_attached_file.rb:65:in `block in define_setter'
activerecord (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:54:in `public_send'
activerecord (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:54:in `_assign_attribute'
activerecord (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:41:in `block in assign_attributes'
actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb:170:in `each_pair'
actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb:170:in `each_pair'
activerecord (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:35:in `assign_attributes'
activerecord (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_record/core.rb:551:in `init_attributes'
activerecord (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_record/core.rb:272:in `initialize'
activerecord (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:61:in `new'
activerecord (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:61:in `new'
actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:114:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:114:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:148:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:231:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:231:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:231:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:231:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:87:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:87:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
actionview (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:236:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:72:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:72:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:41:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:750:in `call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:38:in `call'
rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:257:in `call'
rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:558:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:645:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:378:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:83:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.2.0.beta2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.2.0.beta2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.2.0.beta2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:103:in `call'
rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
railties (4.2.0.beta2) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
railties (4.2.0.beta2) lib/rails/application.rb:161:in `call'
rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'
rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/lint.rb:49:in `_call'
rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/lint.rb:37:in `call'
rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/showexceptions.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/commonlogger.rb:33:in `call'
rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/chunked.rb:54:in `call'
rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:89:in `service'
/Users/arezarazu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/Users/arezarazu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/Users/arezarazu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: Con you show the full stacktrace?

Comment: Not sure if that's what you meant?

Answer (score 9):

Looking at the stack trace and the code you have provided, the problem seems to be the invocation of `has_attached_file` in the `Artist` class.

I would suspect that the problem is caused by incompatibilities between version 3.5.4 of the paperclip gem and Rails 4.2. I would suggest you upgrade the paperclip gem.

In the list of changes for that gem, I see listed for version 4.1.1:

> Bug Fix: Callback chain terminator is different in Rails 4.1, remove
>   warnings

That could well be the culprit.

Comment: I managed to solve the exception and error, by replacing

gem "paperclip", "~> 3.0"

with

gem 'paperclip', github: 'thoughtbot/paperclip' 

However, the images are still not being uploaded, which makes me believe there is still something wrong with the paperclip compatibility. What's the easiest way to troubleshoot gem compatibility issues, making you sure you're using the most stable yet updated set of gems? I'm quite new to rails as you might tell, thank you.

Comment: @Prohairesis did you managed to solve the issue? I run in the same problem using [paperclip-googledrive](https://github.com/evinsou/paperclip-googledrive).

Before adding the `gem paperclip-googledrive`, my Gemfile contained  `gem 'paperclip', github: 'thoughtbot/paperclip'` and all worked fine storing pictures to my filesystem.

Now my `bundle install` fails with the error: `paperclip-googledrive (>= 0) ruby depends on paperclip (~> 3.4) ruby`.
Looks like i'm running in circles. Any clues? Thanks

Comment: @Cristi i had exacly the same problem, did you found a fix?

Comment: This solution worked for me with the same problem! thanks you!

Answer (score 2):

If you're running Rails 4.0+ make sure to change the 'paperclip' gem file to '~> 4.2' as suggested. It would be: 'paperclip', '~>4.2'

Comment: This was the solution for me, during a Rails 3.2->4.2 upgrade