# Rails paperclip's validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, paperclip, production

I'm using paperclip . I have the following model validations in the family. In developer work correctly but in production not work.

```
class Family < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
  has_attached_file :image, styles: { original: "320x240", small: "64x64" }


  validates_presence_of :name, :description
  validates :image, :attachment_presence => true


  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]
  validates_attachment_size :image, :less_than => 10.megabytes
  validates_attachment_size :image, :in => 0.megabytes..1.megabytes

end
```

> I, [2015-01-05T07:45:11.091444 #20474]  INFO -- : Started GET "/families/new?locale=es" for 88.20.141.138 at 2015-01-05 07:45:11 -0500
>   I, [2015-01-05T07:45:11.093468 #20474]  INFO -- : Processing by FamiliesController#new as HTML
>   I, [2015-01-05T07:45:11.093535 #20474]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"locale"=>"es"}
>   D, [2015-01-05T07:45:11.095564 #20474] DEBUG -- :   User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
>   I, [2015-01-05T07:45:11.104610 #20474]  INFO -- :   Rendered families/_form.html.erb (3.7ms)
>   I, [2015-01-05T07:45:11.105000 #20474]  INFO -- :   Rendered families/new.html.erb within layouts/application (6.1ms)
>   I, [2015-01-05T07:45:11.108690 #20474]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (1.9ms)
>   I, [2015-01-05T07:45:11.110200 #20474]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.5ms)
>   I, [2015-01-05T07:45:11.110652 #20474]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 17ms (Views: 13.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
>   I, [2015-01-05T07:45:21.050016 #20474]  INFO -- : Started POST "/families?locale=es" for 88.20.141.138 at 2015-01-05 07:45:21 -0500
>   I, [2015-01-05T07:45:21.051441 #20474]  INFO -- : Processing by FamiliesController#create as HTML
>   I, [2015-01-05T07:45:21.051592 #20474]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"A1ieEMdwYcqAErWmQZF8WBf6lR0qMTTV5DS+r5LfPHsshWapnyEid6forMh/18F5E+T/cW8J+yAacug5OcsxpQ==", "family"=>{"name"=>"fdgsgdf", "description"=>"sdfsdf", "image"=>#, @original_filename="ternera.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"family[image]\"; filename=\"ternera.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, "active"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Guardar", "locale"=>"es"}
>   D, [2015-01-05T07:45:21.053404 #20474] DEBUG -- :   User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
>   I, [2015-01-05T07:45:21.059186 #20474]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7ms
>   F, [2015-01-05T07:45:21.060360 #20474] FATAL -- : 
>   NoMethodError (undefined method `call' for "result == false":String):
>     app/controllers/families_controller.rb:29:in`create'

Comment: Please provide some code from your `families_controller.rb` file.

Comment: your problem is here `app/controllers/families_controller.rb` line number 29 of `create` method

Answer (score 2):

the problem was the parpeclip's version and rails's version. Add  gem 'paperclip', "~> 4.2" to the Gemfile an run bundle install.

[more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26852485/ruby-on-rails-error-undefined-method-call-for-result-falsestring-erro)

Answer (score 2):

If you're running Rails 4.0+ make sure to change the 'paperclip' gem file to '~> 4.2' as suggested. It would be:
'paperclip', '~>4.2'